# Which charge value to use and Why

Tags: electrostatics, charge, units

$1\mu C=10^{-6}C$ vs $e=1.60\times10^{-19}C$. I am having trouble understanding when to use for $q$, $10^{-6}C$ or $1.60\times10^{-19}C$. I had a problem where $a=Eq/m$. I don't know which value of a charge go into the formula. I need to understand why.

Comment: Elementary charge is $e=1.6 \times 10^{-19} \mathrm{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need a consistent set of units.  The equation $a=\frac {Eq}m$ is true in any consistent set.  If you use SI units, $a$ is measured in m/sec$^2$, $E$ in Volts/meter, $q$ in Coulombs, and $m$ in kg.  If you have a single electron charge, it would be $1.6\times 10^{-19}$ coulombs.  If you have a bunch of charges, they might make up a microcoulomb or so.

Comment: Well why do i use for F= (k*q)/r^2, (k* (value*10^-6))/r^2

Comment: Usually $F=k\frac {q_1q_2}{r^2}$  I don't recognize your force equation with only one charge in the numerator.  $k$ has units on it, and they need to be consistent with the units of $q$ and $r$.

Answer (score 0):

$E = k q/r^2$ while $F = k q_1 q_2/r^2$. Perhaps you are getting your equations confused?